# Typing Decorator with Parameters in MyPy with TypeVar yields expected uninhabited type

Tags: python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators, mypy

MyPy has some issues with `Callable` `*args` and `**kwargs`, particularly concerning decorators as detailed in: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1927

Specifically, for a decorator with no parameters which only wraps a function (and does not change its signature), you need the following:

```
from typing import Any, Callable, cast, TypeVar

FuncT = TypeVar('FuncT', bound=Callable[..., Any])

def print_on_call(func: FuncT) -> FuncT:
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Running", func.__name__)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return cast(FuncT, wrapped)
```

The `cast()` at the end should be unnecessary (MyPy should be able to derive that by the invocation of `func` at the end of `wrapped` that wrapped is indeed `FuncT -> FuncT`). I can live with this until it is fixed.

However this breaks horribly when you introduce decorators with parameters. Consider the decorator:

```
def print_on_call(foo):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            print("Running", foo)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return decorator
```

Which is used as so:

```
@print_on_call('bar')
def stuff(a, b):
    return a + b
```

We may attempt to type it (using the parameterless example endorsed by Guido as a guide) like so:

```
from typing import Any, Callable, Dict, List, TypeVar

FuncT = TypeVar('FuncT', bound=Callable[..., Any])

def print_on_call(foo: str) -> Callable[[FuncT], FuncT]:
    def decorator(func: FuncT) -> FuncT:
        def wrapped(*args: List[Any], **kwargs: Dict[str, Any]) -> Any:
            print("Running", foo)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return cast(FuncT, wrapped)
    return cast(Callable[[FuncT], FuncT], decorator)
```

This appears to typecheck, but when we use it:

```
@print_on_call('bar')
def stuff(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b
```

We get a nasty error:

```
error: Argument 1 has incompatible type Callable[[int, int], int]; expected <uninhabited>
```

I'm a little confused as to how this is possible. As discussed in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-variables-with-an-upper-bound), it seems that `Callable[[int, int], int]` should be a subtype of `Callable[..., Any]`.

I assumed that maybe this was a bad iteration between using the generic across the return type of `print_on_call` and a a parameter and return type to `decorator`, so I shaved my example down to the bare minimum (although no longer a working decorator, it still should typecheck):

```
from typing import Any, Callable, Dict, List, TypeVar

FuncT = TypeVar('FuncT', bound=Callable[..., Any])

def print_on_call(foo: str) -> Callable[[FuncT], FuncT]:
    return cast(Callable[[FuncT], FuncT], None)
```

However this still results in the above error. This would be something I'd be okay with just `#type: ignore`ing away, but unfortunately as a result of this problem, any function decorated with this decorator has type `<uninhabited>`, so you start losing type safety everywhere.

**That all said (tl;dr):**

How do you type decorators (which do not modify the function's signature) with parameters? Is the above a bug? Can it be worked around?

MyPy version: 0.501 (the latest as of this posting)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oops! Looks like I didn't search hard enough. There is already an issue and a workaround for this: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1551#issuecomment-253978622

Comment: TypeVar(F,...,Yeah)

Answer (score 13):

nowadays, this is supported by mypy directly:

https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#declaring-decorators

i.e.

```py
FuncT = TypeVar("FuncT", bound=Callable[..., Any]) 

def my_decorator(func: FuncT) -> FuncT:
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        print("something")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return cast(FuncT, wrapped)
```